# Hive connectivity error in Pentaho DI

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, pentaho-data-integration

I am getting a below error while I am trying to do a test connection on hive localhost in pentaho di.

> Error connecting to database [HiveConn] :
> org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: Error occurred while > trying to connect to the database
>
> Error connecting to database: (using class
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver) loader constraint violation: loader > (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a
> different type with name "org/apache/thrift/protocol/TProtocol"
>
> org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
> Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Please let me know what could be the reason.

Comment: Resolved this by changing the driver

Comment: Resolved this by changing the driver